# How to output only the ToC as HTML

Tags: table-of-contents, html, kaobook

I'm using [kaobook](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook) to produce a book that I'm publishing on LeanPub.  LeanPub provides the option to upload an HTML-formatted table of contents.

Is there any way I can output *just* the table of contents in HTML format from my `.tex` files?

I know that with some effort, I can output the entire document to HTML, then extract just the index, but I would like to make this an automated process, for easy reproducibility.

Is this even theoretically possible, considering that the ToC is built from metadata for the entire document?

Comment: Depending on your comfort with programming, a .toc to html converter would not be a difficult thing to write.

Comment: @DonaldHosek: That's a good thought. I could probably throw that together pretty quickly.

Comment: Maybe not even programming is necessary, but a RegExp that can be used with e.g. `sed` or even Notepad++

Comment: I have a nearly complete program to do this now, and I think this is actually the best answer, since it turns out LeanPub supports very limited HTML for their TOCs. I think it's unlikely that any LaTeX-generated HTML would work well.

Comment: So a custom program to produce the HTML is the solution I went with. If @DonaldHosek wants to post an answer to this effect, I'm happy to accept it. Otherwise I can do the same myself later--if such a suggestion truly counts as an answer on this site.